# How to convert a hexstring to shellcode format?

Tags: python, shellcode

I have a bytes key define as:

> KEY = b'\xb5\x89\xd5\x03\x03\x96`\x9dq\xa7\x81\xed\xb2gYR'

I want this to be formatted like shellcode, i.e two hexa characters like: \x41\x42\x43...

So I tried to do it like this:

```
KEY = b'\xb5\x89\xd5\x03\x03\x96`\x9dq\xa7\x81\xed\xb2gYR'
hexkey = KEY.hex()
l = []

for i in range(0, len(hexkey) - 2, 2):
    b = '\\x' + hexkey[i] + hexkey[i+1]
    l.append(b)
```

but this isn't escaping the backslash for some reason, I get this output:

> ['\\xb5', '\\x89', '\\xd5', '\\x03', '\\x03', '\\x96', '\\x60',
> '\\x9d', '\\x71', '\\xa7', '\\x81', '\\xed', '\\xb2', '\\x67',
> '\\x59']

what am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.join()` and `print` them.  You can iterate over the bytes directly as well:

```
KEY = b'\xb5\x89\xd5\x03\x03\x96`\x9dq\xa7\x81\xed\xb2gYR'
print(''.join(f'\\x{b:02x}' for b in KEY))
```

Output:

```
\xb5\x89\xd5\x03\x03\x96\x60\x9d\x71\xa7\x81\xed\xb2\x67\x59\x52
```

Comment: thank you, would you mind explaining the syntax f'\\x{b:02x}'?

Comment: That's called an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals "formatted string literal") and the syntax was added in Python 3.6.  `{b:02x}` says "format value `b` as 2 hex digits with leading zeros".  See the [Format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)